# Equivalent of map.cameraForBounds without a Mapbox GL Map instance

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

With Mapbox GL JS, I can get a center and zoom level to show all of a given bounding box using the [`cameraForBounds`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#cameraforbounds) method:

```
const {center, zoom} = map.cameraForBounds(
  [
    [sw.lng, sw.lat],
    [ne.lng, ne.lat],
  ],
  {
    padding: 20,
    bearing,
    pitch,  // probably ignored?
  },
);
```

(The [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4ba5d8dbca725a9730a091abadf12e6509944c45/types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts#L1600-L1620) say that `pitch` is OK but the [docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#cameraforbounds) don't mention it and neither does [the implementation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/d0f42e4274a0972f27c1e7f1546aea58491d2a4c/src/ui/camera.js#L521-L586), so I assume it's ignored.)

This usually works great, but there occasionally situations where I want to figure out the center/zoom before the map is initialized. It seems like the bounds → camera transformation should just be math, not requiring a Map instance.

How can I go from bounds and bearing (and ideally pitch) to a center/zoom that will include those bounds without an instance of a Mapbox GL map?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for the simple reason that you don't know how many pixels this map will occupy. Setting a centre and zoom determines how much area (and which area) will be covered by each pixel in the middle of the map. The bigger the map DOM element is, the more area will be covered by the area within the map.

Comment: I’m happy to pass a pixel width and height as parameters, that’s no problem.